# Error when creating an application in shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I'm trying to create a custom app for shopify by entering this command into the terminal:

```
shopify app create php
```

and after specifying the `app name` and selecting `store`, I get this error:

```
PHP is required to create an app project. For installation instructions, visit:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php
```

I understand that this error indicates a lack of `php`, but where should I set the language of `php`? on my computer?

I'm new to app development in shopify. And usually, I make plugins or server-side app, but this error is new to me.

Please tell me what I need to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kuznetsov

You need to install **PHP** the easiest way to install PHP is by installing **packages** like **Xampp, Wamp, Mamp** or you can install PHP **stand-alone**

1. https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
2. https://www.wampserver.com/en/
3. https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/
4. https://www.php.net/downloads

for testing, if you have successfully installed PHP, use in command prompt

```
PHP -v
```

it should show the installed version.

**PHP Version:**
[image: PHP Version]

**Xampp:**
[image: Xampp]